# Xcode crashes when trying to run project due to LLDB

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, xcode5, lldb

When I click 'Run', Xcode crashes instantly, regardless of my code.
The crash report says that the LLDB plugin can not be read correctly:

```
Error getting value for key 'workerClass' of extension 'Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.Debugger.LLDB' in plug-in 'com.apple.dt.dbg.DebuggerLLDB'
```

The crash report:

```
Process:         Xcode [2184]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         5.0.2 (3335.32)
Build Info:      IDEApplication-3335032000000000~4
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [147]
Responsible:     Xcode [2184]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2014-02-26 18:41:28.657 +0100
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.2 (13C64)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  B5F54D76-660F-C9CE-0C9C-D0D41BA7332B

Sleep/Wake UUID: 9A19E5A2-14DE-40FF-8993-668257EF9F44

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
Sending performRunAction: to <IDERunPauseContinueToolbarButton: 0x7f8494673e80> from <IDERunPauseContinueToolbarButton: 0x7f8494673e80>
ProductBuildVersion: 5A3005
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInternalInconsistencyException): Error getting value for key 'workerClass' of extension 'Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.Debugger.LLDB' in plug-in 'com.apple.dt.dbg.DebuggerLLDB'
UserInfo: {
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=DVTPlugInErrorDomain Code=2 \"Loading a plug-in failed.\" UserInfo=0x7f8496dca9a0 {DVTPlugInIdentifierErrorKey=com.apple.dt.dbg.DebuggerLLDB, DVTPlugInExecutablePathErrorKey=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DebuggerLLDB, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=The plug-in or one of its prerequisite plug-ins may be missing or damaged and may need to be reinstalled., NSLocalizedDescription=Loading a plug-in failed., NSFilePath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.ideplugin, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The plug-in \U201ccom.apple.dt.dbg.DebuggerLLDB\U201d at path \U201c/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.ideplugin\U201d could not be loaded.  The plug-in or one of its prerequisite plug-ins may be missing or damaged., NSUnderlyingError=0x7f8496dc98f0 \"The bundle \U201cDebuggerLLDB\U201d couldn\U2019t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources.\"}";
}
Hints: 
  0: Sending performRunAction: to <IDERunPauseContinueToolbarButton: 0x7f8494673e80> from <IDERunPauseContinueToolbarButton: 0x7f8494673e80>
  1: Sending performAction: to <DVTDelayedMenuButtonCell: 0x7f8494674490> from <IDERunPauseContinueToolbarButton: 0x7f8494673e80>
Backtrace:
  0  0x00007fff91211244 __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1  0x00000001082ddd73 DVTFailureHintExceptionPreprocessor (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x00007fff940a2e75 objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  3  0x000000010826bcd2 -[DVTExtension valueForKey:] (in DVTFoundation)
  4  0x000000010d3d1109 -[DBGLLDBDebugLocalService operationWorkerWithLaunchSession:error:] (in DebuggerLLDBService)
  5  0x0000000110106e17 -[IDERuniPhoneSimulatorService operationWorkerWithLaunchSession:error:] (in IDEiOSSupportCore)
  6  0x0000000108d38d49 -[IDERunDestination runWorkerForLaunchSession:error:] (in IDEFoundation)
  7  0x0000000108d38a74 -[IDERunDestination runOperationForLaunchSession:error:] (in IDEFoundation)
  8  0x0000000108da0fee -[IDELaunchSchemeAction runOperationForExecutionEnvironment:withBuildOperation:buildParameters:buildableProductDirectories:schemeActionRecord:outError:actionCallbackBlock:] (in IDEFoundation)
  9  0x0000000108d94f5b -[IDEScheme _executionOperationForExecutionEnvironment:build:onlyBuild:buildPurpose:buildCommand:schemeCommand:title:overridingProperties:destination:buildLog:filePath:overridingBuildConfiguration:restorePersistedBuildResults:invocationRecord:overridingTestingSpecifiers:error:actionCallbackBlock:] (in IDEFoundation)
```

This may happen due to a broken LLDB debugger, which could only be solved by Apple.
However, I haven't found many similar problems from others on the internet yet, so this may only happen with my Xcode.

Comment: Did you try to reinstall Xcode?

Comment: Try reinstalling Xcode.

Comment: Not really programming related, though.

Comment: Yes I tried, reinstalling Xcode didn't work.

Comment: A very similar issue (but not strictly identical) and how I fixed it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22849021/xcode-5-1-crashes-when-it-hits-a-break-point/23327652#23327652

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem: was not able to run any Xcode projects. Reason was I was playing around on Python and downgraded it to 2.6.8 from 2.7.x. So, I have updated the python to 2.7.8 from older version, No problems so far, Xcode deploys everything very smoothly. Other things that I have tried was even uninstalling the X-code and install again, this didn't help. Very useful page to upgrade your python on macbook : http://wolfpaulus.com/jounal/mac/installing_python_osx/

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with your project. Somehow the Xcode.app that you launched has been damaged. Try downloading the latest Xcode from the App Store or ADC.

If this don't helps, try to report your problem: [Apple Bug Reporter](http://bugreport.apple.com/)

Comment: yea, this is pretty new problem, sorry

Comment: Thank you anyway. You know, the worst problems are these you can not solve by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone still has the same problem, Apple told me that this happens if a wrong "custom" version of Python is installed. I installed Python 2.7.6 and it worked.